# put the logo webview - Android

Tags: android

I want to put a logo on the corner of the webview. Because I don't want users to download pdf while pdf is loading. So I want to add a logo to the top right corner of the webview. But when I add the logo it stays under the webview and is not visible. How can I show it on top of the webview and in the top right corner?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="...">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:title="Home" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        tools:openDrawer="end"
        android:layoutDirection="ltr">
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageAntremanLogo"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/webviewAntreman"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_kopya"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webviewAntreman"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I noticed you already received some answers for your question but both seemed to miss some points I noticed hence decided to post an answer.

First, as @Ryan's answer mentioned you will need to put your `ImageView` after `WebView` in order for it to be drawn on top, otherwise it would always be below.

Second, upto this your `ImageView` should be on top-left, but since you require it to be on the Top-Right corner you will need to add

```
android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/webviewAntreman"
```

So your `ImageView` code written **after** the `WebView` woul be something like this.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageAntremanLogo"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/webviewAntreman"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/webviewAntreman"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_kopya"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />
```

As a note, `android:elevation` as in @Rumit's answer requires minimum API level 21, so if your app supports version below Android 5.0 this property won't work on those otherwise it's fine.

In the rare case none of this works, make use of a `FrameLayout` for what you need to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Put the `ImageView` tag after the `WebView` tag in the XML.  Views are drawn with the last one on top.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **`android:elevation="5dp"`** property on `ImageView` to elevate it from `WebView`.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageAntremanLogo"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/webviewAntreman"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_kopya"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />
```